# Is there an alternative Ctrl+C to stop a rails server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, command-line

My keyboard had an unfortunate accident and now certain key and key combinations will not work. I am using a bash shell to issue commands. I saw that using Ctrl-Pause/Break may be able to stop the server on a couple posts like [this](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Hardware/HP-Envy-2-pause-key/m-p/3557595#M120646) but my keyboard is mapped so that Fn + right-shift is for pause and Ctrl + Fn + right-shift is for break [As detailed on the HP Support Forum Home](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Hardware/HP-Envy-2-pause-key/m-p/3557595#M120646). This didn't work for me as it could be how my keyboard is mapped or that it is yet another thing by keyboard now will not do. Is there any other way I can tell the server to stop?

Edit: I'm using an external keyboard now. though I find myself trying to use my laptop's built in keyboard.

Comment: You can send it SIGINT or SIGTERM via `kill`. Or you could spend $10 and get an external keyboard.

Comment: @ChrisHeald Thank you a quick search on that suggests that SIGINT is the better command to use if there is a choice found [here](http://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-the-SIGINT-and-SIGTERM-signals-in-Linux) . I'm new to bash. I entered in the SIGINT command and it said the "command not found". Is there any particular way I need to issue this command?

Comment: You can try re-mapping "Caps Lock" as control for that old-school keyboard feel.

Comment: The `kill` command sends the signal for you (`SIGTERM` by default). You do `kill pid`, where `pid` is the process ID. If you know the name of the process, you can obtain the pid using `pgrep name`.

Comment: You can also use pkill to kill by name, ie `pkill -f unicorn`.

Comment: Alternatively you could get the pid using `pidof <command name>`. Besides the formatting, the command is equivalent to `pgrep`. I advise you write a simple shell script to start the server, when it does you can then store the pid of the server process and terminate it later. This will avoid closing down other processes which can be an undesirable side-effect using `kill $(pgrep command)`, `kill command` or `kill $(pidof command)`.

Comment: I didn't understood if CTRL key is still usable. If yes try if works `CTRL-Z` and after that the shell answers you with the message similar to e.g `[3] Stopped`, you can do your `kill %3` (3 is the job number inside `[x]`) eventually giving the signal you need if different from SIGTERM ( Get the full list with `kill -l`).

Answer (score 3):

You can find the rails process by using the `ps` command like this:

```
 ➜ ps aux
```

You see a list of everything running on your system. Look for a line that shows your Rails app.

For example I use Passenger to run my app, my app name is "demo", and my process line is:

```
me 30704 0.0 2.0 705696 155300 ? Sl 18:58 0:01 Passenger RackApp: demo
```

The process line shows you two items you may need:

- The second item is the process id number, also known as the PID.
- The ending text is the name of the running application and its arguments.

Kill the process by sending the signal INT to the PID:

```
➜ kill -s INT 30704
```

The signals that you may want:

- `INT` means "program interrupt" and is sent when the user types the INTR character (normally C-c).
- `TERM` is a generic polite way to ask a program to terminate.
- `KILL` causes immediate program termination. It cannot be handled, ignored, or blocked.

If you have to do this more than once, then there are shortcuts.

To find the process line, you can use `grep` or similar tools such as `pgrep` or `pidof`.

```
 ➜ ps aux | grep Passenger
```

To find the process id number, you can use `awk` to print the line's second item:

```
 ➜ ps aux | grep Passenger | awk '{print $2}'
```

To kill all processes with a specific pattern in the name or arguments, you can use `pkill`:

```
 ➜ pkill -f Passenger
```

Answer (score 0):

To stop the rails server while it's running, press:

CTRL-Z

Comment: This won't "stop" it in the expected ("kill") sense.